# Is there a tool to model rigging

Tags: hanging

Say I want to hang a shelf to the ceiling: [image: Like this] Given that points A,B,C,D are fixed on the ceiling, and points a,b,c,d are fixed connection points on the shelf.

1) Is it possible to control pan and tilt (yaw and pitch) of the shelf by the lengths of the ropes Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd ?

2) If possible, what's the best tool to model/calculate it?

3) If already modeled, how can I check if the shelf is stable against lateral forces.

Comment: 1) pitch and bank but not yaw. 2) pencil, paper, trig. 3) It won't be stable against lateral forces. You need cross-bracing. You also need either ropes bracing from below or struts good in compression as well as tension.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick You can actually control all three orientations of the shelf by using different suspension lengths and angles, but you probably don't want to (see my answer).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick If I assume that there's no risk of corner of the shelf being lifted up -- how many cross ropes is needed to keep shelf in one place when it's center of mass moves around due to load. I'm thinking that two should be enough, if they're perpendicular from top layout?

Comment: @Gleb: A leftward horizontal force on the far right edge would make the surface pivot around C-D if there were a bracing rope from C to a. The ropes A-a and hypothetical A-c would just go slack. Thus the table would tilt and your Ming vases cascade onto the marble floor. If having trouble visualising how this works, I suggest experimenting with an old cardboard box, some string and a postcard :-)

Comment: Horizontal rope from a and c to some fixed points on the wall leftward and rightward respectively should do what I think you want. (This is what Daniel Griscom's answer says)

Answer (score 1):

If the suspension ropes aren't vertical, then you're making a (3D) trapezoid linkage, and changing the tension balance between the ropes (which will happen whenever you move the shelf contents around) will change both the horizontal position and the tilt of the suspended shelf.

Assuming you don't want the shelf contents spilling off, you should have each of the suspension ropes be vertical, which will make the shelf position and orientation independent of the load. However, @RedGrittyBrick is right: you'll need some sort of lateral support to keep the shelf from rocking back and forth; either cross-bracing, or horizontal bracing to nearby fixed points.